# C pointers. Assignement of large numbers to char * pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "malloc.h"

int main()

{

    char*x=(char*)malloc(1024);
    *(x+2)=3; -----------------------------> Problem with big numbers 
    printf("\n%d",*(x+2));
    printf("\n%d",sizeof(long int));
    printf("\n %ld \n\n",(long int)sizeof(long int));
}
```

This works fine when I give small numbers in the line marked with an arrow (`------->`), but does not work for large values. I want to store big numbers. What should I do?

Comment: Please post a code example of what you mean by a "big number".

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
int main()
{
 char*x=(char*)malloc(1024);
 *(x+2)=319222; // -------- this wont work. It says overflow problem. 
 printf("\n%d",*(x+2));
 printf("\n%d",sizeof(long int));
 printf("\n %ld \n\n",(long int)sizeof(long int));
}

Comment: What do you expect to happen? `char` is only guaranteed to hold values up to 127 (or 255).

Comment: Sorry for messing it out here. I mean to say *(x+2)=319222 doesnot work.

Comment: enable warnings: `-Wall`

Comment: Ya.. Exactly. I want to store large numbers in void * buffer but that does not allow me to do arithmetic operations like *(x+2)

Answer (score 2):

You are allocating a `char` buffer. The elements of such an array is only guaranteed to hold small values, at most up to 255. If you want to store numeric values, use some numeric array instead (e.g. `long` or `int`, depending on how large the desired values actually are). E.g.

```
long* x = (long*)malloc(1024 * sizeof(long));
x[2] = 319222; // x[2] is equivalent to *(x+2)
```

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/climits/) you can check the limits for all scalar data types in C.

Comment: malloc caster should programming in C++ not in C

Answer (score 1):

Use a larger type, like an `int` or a `long`. In C, `char` is usually only an 8 bit quantity which will be limited to a valid range of +/- 128.

Comment: Ya.. Exactly. I want to store large numbers in void * buffer but that does not allow me to do arithmetic operations like *(x+2)

Comment: And i have to do it void * buffer only

Answer (score 0):

All the buffer allocation and pointer arithmetic is getting in the way of understanding. Essentially the issue is that char has a limited range, typically -127 to 128 or 0 to 255.

The simplest way to see your problem is with code like this:

```
char c = 256;//no good
int i = 256;//no problem
```

From what you have said in the comments, it sounds like you want to cast the char* to int* and write over the buffer that way. I hope you know what you are doing.

```
*(int*)x[2] = 666;
```

Comment: On which compiler does that not compile? gcc only warns about the first assignment.

Comment: @bitmask C really does let you get away with murder!

Comment: C is anarchy! That's the beauty of C.